# How to make a new log-flie using log4j every time i run a class? and also how to make separate logfiles class wise but in same project.?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, log4j, log4j2

have a maven project with of selenium testing automation and i have also implemented log 4j for logging .
now my question is that

- How to make a new log-flie using log4j every time i run a class?
- and also how to make separate logfiles class wise but in same project.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.